# Comparing javascript array values

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.onload=function(){
        contents = new Array();
        painted = new Array();
        keys = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            contents[i] = '';
            painted[i] = false;
        }
        contents[0] = 1;

    }

    function clicked(canvasNumber){
        if(contents[canvasNumber-1] == 1;){
            alert("you won!");
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get a pop up saying, "you won!" when canvas 1 is clicked, but the contents of my contents array are not matching up to trigger that alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also want to add that all variables have already been declared.

Comment: How are you calling `clicked` ?

Comment: In addition to the semi-colon answer below, have you defined `contents` outside the functions to make it a global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(contents[canvasNumber-1] == 1;){
```

should be

```
if(contents[canvasNumber-1] == 1){
```

with no semicolon in the if statement

Also your indexes are most likely not aligned.